Passing object through navigation in Jetpack Compose
I am fairly new to android development and had a question about best practices for this scenario. I am making a simple android app that generates a list of randomly generated Drinks in on screen (the drinks wouldn't be in a repository at this point). When the user clicks on a drink, I want to navigate to a Edit Drink page and fill it with the details. Google suggests using a viewModel to pass complicated data across destinations.
My approach was to put the Drink objects into a shared viewModel when the user clicks on a drink, which would be accessible by the EditDrink destination. Because of the complexity of the EditDrink destination however, I also want it to have it's own specialized view model. Therefore, I would have to pass the selected drink from the shared viewModel into my EditDrinkViewModel, I can do this through the 'EditDrinksViewModel constructor by using a viewModel factory, but at this point I was questioning if my approach was really the best practice. If not what would be the recommended approach? Thanks!

Hey @Tyler, are you using type-safe navigation?

@Mohammad, I currently am not, but I am a little familiar with the idea of type-safe navigation. As I mentioned in my question, I was worried about the guideline to not pass in complex data as a navigation argument. I didn't know it that meant any non-primative object was discouraged, or just really large ones.

I understand that it was acceptable to pass a single object.

If you are still afraid to pass the object, then the best practice is to just pass the unique reference(ID) and get data from the data sources.

@TylerAllen - Similar question which might provide some help.

@Mohammad - Thanks for clarifying! Passing it in as a navigation argument really simplifies my problem.

@TylerAllen It's good to hear that. Keep coding!
